# I am not sure why am i keep getting error. history.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

```
var history=[];
function log(p,i,pm,y,m)
{
   var details = {
      amt:p,
      int:i,
      paym:pm,
      yea:y,
      mon:m
   };
   history.push(details); //error is here. Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function

   var currDetails = history[history.length-1];
   document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += currDetails.amt;
}
```

I am trying push the data into history array. But, why am i keep getting error?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are accessing the global window property [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) and it is read only. You are getting the error because there is no `push()` implemented on that property. Try some other name so that it does not match with any of the [global window property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) to get the expected behavior from the declared variable:

```js
var historyArr=[];
function log(p,i,pm,y,m)
{
  var details = {
    amt:p,
    int:i,
    paym:pm,
    yea:y,
    mon:m
  };
  historyArr.push(details);

  var currDetails = historyArr[historyArr.length-1];
  console.log(currDetails)
}

log('a','b','c','d','e');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [global variable `history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) is predefined in browsers and is read only.

`var history=[];` therefore fails silently.

`history.push` therefore fails because `history` is not an array object.

Wrap your code in an IIFE so that you aren't trying to create unneeded variables in the global scope, this will mean you can create a `history` variable as you won't be overwriting the existing one.

```js
var log = (function() {

  var history = [];

  function log(p, i, pm, y, m) {
    var details = {
      amt: p,
      int: i,
      paym: pm,
      yea: y,
      mon: m
    };
    history.push(details); //error is here. Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function

    var currDetails = history[history.length - 1];
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += currDetails.amt;
  }

  return log;

})();
```

(This is a simplified version of [the revealing module pattern](http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/REVEALING_MODULE_PATTERN.md).